# Expansion issue with \begingroup and \foreach

Tags: expansion

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`nowidow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nowidow)

I'm trying to define a dynamic `\begingroup` command to get rid of widows:

```
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\nowidow}[1][2]{%
 \begingroup\widowpenalties #1 \foreach \n in {2,...,#1}{10000 } 0 
 \par\endgroup
}
```

This fails complaining that `\begingroup` requires a number and I'm guessing this has to do with expansion.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\nowidow}[1][2]{%
 \begingroup\widowpenalties #1 \foreach \n in {2,...,#1}{10000 } 0
 \par\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\nowidow

\end{document}
```

How can I get this to work? Would it be easier (although less portable) to do it in Lua?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\begingroup` doesn't require a number. It is `\widowpenalties` which looks for one and `\foreach` isn't expandable, so it doesn't produce a number directly and therefore you get an error. Most likely `\begingroup` is just shown somewhere in the error message because it was the last correctly read token before the error.

In order to fix this you need to use an expandable loop, e.g. using e-TeX's `\numexpr`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\nowidowX#1{%
    \ifnum#1<\nowidowmax
        10000
        \expandafter\nowidowX\expandafter{\the\numexpr(#1)+1\expandafter\relax\expandafter}%
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\nowidow}[1][2]{%
    \begingroup
    \mathchardef\nowidowmax#1\relax
    \widowpenalties #1 \nowidowX{1} 0\par
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\nowidow

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I use an expandable loop?

Comment: I added some code now.

Comment: @Martin: you save a few `\expandafter` if you make the argument of `\nowidowX` delimited (e.g., `\def\nowidowX#1;{\ifnum#1<\nowidowmax10000 \expandafter\nowidowX\the\numexpr#1+1\expandafter;\fi}`).

Answer (score 3):

Martin has already pointed out that `\foreach` is non-expandable. I'd add that the `expl3` bundle provides such expandable tools. For instance,

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\nowidow} { O{2} }
  {
     \begingroup
     \widowpenalties #1~ \prg_replicate:nn {#1-1} {10000~} 0~
     \par\endgroup
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

(I'm just using xparse for `\NewDocumentCommand`. You could simply stick with `\newcommand` if you prefer.)

Comment: This is latex3, right?

Comment: @Raphink, yes. I should add that spaces are ignored between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `Off` and the odd-looking `~` are spaces. Basically, I replicate `10000~` a given number of times. Also, it seems that the last `0` penalty is not really needed, is it? You could put `\widowpenalties \int_eval:n{#1-1}~ \prg_replicate:nn...` and remove that `0~`.